# Handling for multiple countries with distinction blocks (with episerver9.1 C#)

Tags: c#, episerver

```
public class EpiBlock : SiteBlockData
{
    [Display(Name = "SomeCommonData", GroupName = Global.GroupNames.Settings.General)]
    [EditorDescriptor(EditorDescriptorType = typeof(RolesEditorDescriptor))]
    public virtual string SomeCommonData { get; set; }
}

public class Controller : BlockControllerBase<EpiBlock>
{
    private readonly IVmBuilder _vmBuilder;

    public Controller(IVmBuilder vmBuilder)
    {
        _vmBuilder = vmBuilder;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(EpiBlock epiBlock, VmContext context)
    {
        Vm<EpiBlock> vm = _vmBuilder.CreateVm(epiBlock, context);

        return PartialView(vm.ViewName, vm);
    }
}
```

//How to handle extended EpiBlockHungary in episerver, registration and this controller

//Is it possible to use the same controller and page where this block exists (for EpiBlock and EpiBlockHungary)?

```
public class EpiBlockHungary : EpiBlock
{
    [Display(Name = "SomeHungarianData", GroupName = Global.GroupNames.Settings.General)]
    [EditorDescriptor(EditorDescriptorType = typeof(RolesEditorDescriptor))]
    public virtual string SomeHungarianData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate the controller with the [TemplateDescriptor](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-CMS/9/Rendering/template-descriptor/) attribute and set its Inherited property to true:

```
[TemplateDescriptor(Inherited=true)]
public class Controller : BlockControllerBase<EpiBlock>
{
}
```